# Polynomial reduction proprietries: reflexive, transitive, but not symmetric

Tags: reductions

From theory I know the polynomial reduction is:

1. reflexive $A ≤ A$ (A Language)
2. transitive $A ≤ B$ and $ B ≤ C$, then $A ≤ C$ (A, B, and C Languages).

What about symmetric? There is an example with two language $L_1$ and $L_2$ to proof the polynomial reduction is not symmetric? i.e. $L_1 ≤ L_2$ but not $L_2 ≤ L_1$.

Comment: Yes, there exist such examples. If you try hard enough you will find them.

Comment: maybe from $L_{SAT}$ (is in NP) to $L_{HALT}$ (is NP-hard)